# How do I reload a file in a buffer?

Tags: files, revert-buffer

I usually work on files which are updated in the file system via version control. What's a quick way to reload a file without having to `C-x C-f` the file again and getting asked if I want to reload it?

Comment: See related question: How to revert all buffers https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/24459

Comment: Short cut "M-Esc v" is working for me.

Comment: LIkely that `C-x C-v RET` is what you're looking for, per @Tikthon below. This is my 3rd round of having forgotten this and coming back to this question, so actually leaving this comment here for future me.

Answer (score 194, accepted):

`M-x revert-buffer` will do exactly what you want. It will still ask for confirmation.

Another option (my favorite) is the below function:

```el
;; Source: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/misc-cmds.el
(defun revert-buffer-no-confirm ()
    "Revert buffer without confirmation."
    (interactive)
    (revert-buffer :ignore-auto :noconfirm))
```

Comment: You might have cited the library that that code is from: [`misc-cmds.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/misc-cmds.el). Not that it is complicated, but when you copy something *exactly* it is common courtesy to point to the source.

Comment: Apologies! I, myself, wasn't sure where I got that snippet from. I should have at least googled the function name and try to find its source so that I can credit it here. **Update** I have noted down the sources for everything I copied; just wasn't sure about this one: https://github.com/kaushalmodi/.emacs.d/blob/master/setup-files/setup-windows-buffers.el

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this function. It's too dangerous to use accidentally on a modified file.

Comment: @Gilles I agree, with great power comes great responsibility. I wouldn't bind that to an easy to access binding.

Comment: @Gilles: MS Windows users are used to using `F5` to revert buffers, pages, whatever, everywhere. I bind this command to `F5`, and I use it all the time. Do you unbind `g` in Dired because `revert-buffer` is dangerous? One person's danger is another person's convenience - your car and bicycle are dangerous too.

Comment: My variant of this will prompt for confirmation only if the buffer is modified, using `(revert-buffer t (not (buffer-modified-p)) t)`.

Comment: You can also use "C-x C-v" shortcut

Comment: `(global-set-key (kbd "<f5>") 'revert-buffer-no-confirm)`

Comment: Can I run it automatically on the background if a change is triggered

Comment: @glucas I have tried to replace the last line in this answer by your code, but Emacs 27.1 gives me an error. Do you know why?

Answer (score 86):

There is also `auto-revert-mode` which does it automatically and gives you feedback.

From the doc string:

```
auto-revert-mode is an interactive autoloaded compiled Lisp function
in `autorevert.el'.

(auto-revert-mode &optional ARG)

Toggle reverting buffer when the file changes (Auto Revert mode).
With a prefix argument ARG, enable Auto Revert mode if ARG is
positive, and disable it otherwise.  If called from Lisp, enable
the mode if ARG is omitted or nil.

Auto Revert mode is a minor mode that affects only the current
buffer.  When enabled, it reverts the buffer when the file on
disk changes.

Use `global-auto-revert-mode' to automatically revert all buffers.
Use `auto-revert-tail-mode' if you know that the file will only grow
without being changed in the part that is already in the buffer.
```

Comment: How can I enable `auto-revert-tail-mode` doing : `(setq auto-revert-tail-mode 1)`?

Comment: The thing with this mode is that I can start typing before it notices the change, or not?

Comment: It is possible to start typing before `emacs` reverts a buffer, but it will not let you do it right away. It will ask you: "... is changed on disk; really edit the buffer (y, n, r or C-h)".

Answer (score 76):

Another option, which I use, is `find-alternate-file` bound to `C-x C-v`. This opens a file reusing your current buffer.

By default, it points to the file you're currently on, so you can just type `C-x C-v RET` to reload your file. It won't prompt unless your buffer has unsaved data.

Some non-text modes like `image-mode` (used for rendering pictures, pdfs, svgs...etc) and `dired` have `revert-buffer` bound to `g` for faster access.

Comment: This is my new go to. Thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: I had a (ffap-bindings) in my .emacs which seems to change the binding of `C-x C-v`.

Comment: This is great, thanks! Simple and effective. Btw, how to make Emacs notice the current file changed? For instance VIM in GUI mode detects a file change automatically when the app gets focus (it is switched to from background).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I like that is short and nice, but unlike the `revert-buffer` it resets point position in the buffer.

Comment: The only issue with this is that it's too easy to hit `C-x C-c` by mistake instead.

Comment: @ijoseph Haha, that's a good point—didn't think of it myself because I unbound `C-x C-c` years ago :P

Answer (score 14):

Emacs calls this [`reverting`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Reverting.html#Reverting).

You can revert the current file with `M-x revert-buffer`. This prompts for confirmation whether the file has been modified or not, except for files that match patterns listed in the variable `revert-without-query` (see the manual for details). Another occasional annoyance of `revert-buffer` is that it resets the file mode to the default.

I use the following function to revert a bunch of files, given by name. If a file isn't opened in some buffer, it is ignored.

```
(defun revert-files (&rest files)
  "Reload all specified files from disk.
Only files that are currently visited in some buffer are reverted.
Do not ask confirmation unless the buffer is modified."
  (save-excursion
    (let ((revert-without-query '("")))
      (dolist (file-name files)
        (message "Considering whether to revert file %s" file-name)
        (let ((buf (find-buffer-visiting file-name)))
          (when buf
            (message "Reverting file in buffer %s" (buffer-name buf))
            (set-buffer buf)
        (revert-buffer t nil t)))))))
```

A typical use case for this function is after updating files from version control. Use `emacsclient` to call `revert-files` on all the files that have been updated, or (this is easier, and only slightly slower) on all the files concerned by the update. I call the following shell script, passing it the files as arguments:

```
#! /bin/sh
# Similar to gnuclient, but call `revert-files' on the files.
files=

## Find a way to convert a path to absolute. Bizarre OSes such as Windows
## require special cases. We also try to detect non-filenames such as URIs.
case `uname -s` in
  CYGWIN*)
    absolute_path () {
      cygpath -a -w -- "$1"
    };;
  *)
    wd="`pwd -P 2>/dev/null || pwd`"
    absolute_path () {
      case "$1" in
        /*) printf '%s' "$1";; # ordinary absolute path
        *:/*)
          if expr "z$1" : 'z[0-9A-Z_a-z][-.0-9@A-Z_a-z]*:/.*'; then
            printf '%s' "$1" # URI or machine:/some/path
          else
            printf '%s' "$wd/$1" # default to a relative path
          fi;;
        *) printf '%s' "$wd/$1";; # default to a relative path
      esac
    };;
esac

for x; do
  files="$files \"`absolute_path "$x" | sed 's/[\\\\\\\"]/\\\\&/g'`\""
done
exec emacsclient -e "(revert-files$files)"
```

Usage example:

```
svn update
find -name .svn -prune -o -type f -exec emacsclient-revert {} +
```

Comment: These days, as @webappzero says in his answer, magit solves this part of the file-reverting problem painlessly

Answer (score 11):

`revert-buffer` is there. But I like to have some feedback.

I have the following in my `.emacs`.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c r") (lambda ()
                                (interactive)
                                (revert-buffer t t t)
                                (message "buffer is reverted")))
```

Answer (score 10):

you can also enable global-auto-revert-mode as shown below

`(global-auto-revert-mode 1)`

this is helpful when you do a lot of checks of your js files with auto-fix mode enabled, like in jssc.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `find-alternate-file`, which is bound to <kbd>C-x C-v</kbd> by default, and just simply type <kbd>RET</kbd> at the prompt to reload the file.

Answer (score 7):

For spacemacs users: `SPC b R` (`spacemacs/safe-revert-buffer`).

For skipping confirmation, other answers already cover that, though I agree with others that it's probably not a good idea to bind that to a key.

Answer (score 5):

Magit manages file reversions for you automatically, thus solving your core problem. You also benefit from its other features.

Here are [the docs](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Automatic-Reverting-of-File_002dVisiting-Buffers.html#Automatic-Reverting-of-File_002dVisiting-Buffers) for tweaking the settings you're interested in:

If you stick with Magit, also be sure to [enable all 3 global WIP modes](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Wip-Modes.html) (Work In Progress) to avoid losing work.

You can thus perform version-control actions inside Emacs with Magit and avoid your original problem altogether.

Comment: Please let me know if this is helpful.

Comment: This answer should have more upvotes!  In case not clear: the WIP modes may be good (I don't use them currently), but they're not strictly necessary in order for it to solves the revert problem for you.

Comment: It is possible to start typing before `emacs` reverts a buffer, but it will not let you do it right away. It will ask you: "... is changed on disk; really edit the buffer (y, n, r or C-h)".

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is a built-in function named `revert-buffer-quick` which does the trick ([source](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Reverting.html)). It checks if you have unsaved modification on the buffer, if there is any, it asks for confirmation, otherwise it will revert (i.e. reload) the file. The default keybinding in vanilla emacs is `C-x x g` which is long, so I have bound it to <kbd>F5</kbd> as well:

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "<f5>") 'revert-buffer-quick)
```