# What is the best way to reload git stashed changes you've popped while file is open in buffer?

Tags: git, magit, revert-buffer

When I'm viewing a file and then pop a stash which modifies that file in the working tree using `git stash pop` in either bash or eshell, what is the best way to immediately see those changes in the buffer visiting that file?

Usually I end up using `C-x C-f` or `M-x revert-buffer` but that's a bit slow. It would be nice to find a mode that automatically updates buffers when the files they visit change on disk.

I've heard of git-modes for viewing diffs or conflicts, but haven't found much for stashing/popping or cherry-picking.

Comment: See also [How do I reload a file in a buffer?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/169/how-do-i-reload-a-file-in-a-buffer/355#355)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you use [`magit`](http://magit.github.io/) you can create a stash with the `z z` command from the `magit-status` buffer. You can also pop a stash using the `A` command.

If you use these commands, affected files will be automatically reverted (changes are loaded).

Check out the [`magit documentation`](http://magit.github.io/documentation.html) for more info on how to use `magit` effectively.

Comment: Installed with el-get and the docs are great. Thank you!

Comment: I usually prefer to use `a` instead of `A` so I don't loose the stash until I'm satisfied with the result. Then you can kill the stash

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @elemakil running a Magit command causes buffers that visit files inside the same repository to be reverted when they change on disk.

This mode only does something after you have used a Magit command. If you run a Git command in bash or eshell then [`magit-auto-revert-mode`](https://github.com/magit/magit/blob/c29b17d28b8eab5051012b9894ab191a43d563be/magit.el#L1095) does not kick in.

However that mode is just a specialized variant of [`global-auto-revert-mode`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Reverting.html). The latter works regardless of what causes a file to change on disk.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't want to accidentally loose any edits in buffers I have open, I have a key bound to [revert all buffers](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/50730/2418), I just run this command when making large changes to the repository which Emacs's wont be tracking.