# How to cancel a mini-buffer prompt from elisp, eg: "... changed on disk; really edit this buffer?"

Tags: revert-buffer

Sometimes I get a mini-buffer prompt to check if I want to edit the buffer.

Instead of answering this, I would like to [revert all buffers](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/50730/2418), however this prompt remains.

How could I cancel this prompt? (which is no longer needed when reverting all buffers)

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 1):

Based upon a reading of the code for the function `ask-user-about-supersession-threat`, it *may* be sufficient to use `(signal 'file-supersession (list "My custom message"))` to cancel the mini-buffer prompt from elisp.  See also the functions `abort-recursive-edit` ["*Abort the command that requested this recursive edit or minibuffer input.*"] and `top-level` ["*Exit all recursive editing levels. This also exits all active minibuffers.*"]

Comment: `(signal 'file-supersession (list "My custom message"))` displays a message but the mini-buffer prompt remains. The issue with `abort-recursive-edit` and `top-level` is they both are `noreturn` functions, making them complicate functions you might want to call when composing functionality.